# I convey the invisible

Tags: riddle

I convey the invisible,

**I convey what can be felt,**

But not seen,

Inside my heart,

**I am not as nice as I could seem to be,**

That is because I deliver the invisible,

At the speed of a mere blink,

I am very powerful,

And can bring comfort,

Across my horizons, I am free,

But still vulnerable to your opinion.

***What am I?***

Comment: Light  or vision ?

Comment: Well god, got any more hints? I'm really curious

Answer (score 4):

It could be a

> Smile

I convey the invisible,

> Emotions are invisible.

I convey what can be felt,

> Emotions, indeed.

But not seen,

> Again, emotions are invisible.

Inside my heart,
I am not as nice as I could seem to be,

> Sometimes smiles are fake.

That is because I deliver the invisible,

> Again...

At the speed of a mere blink,

> Muscles movements are fast as for smiles, as for blinks.

I am very powerful,
And can bring comfort,

> A smile brings happiness, usually.

Across my horizons, I am free,

> What's the price of a smile?

But still vulnerable to your opinion.

> It's not easy to tell a true smile from a fake one.

Comment: Good try but not the right answer.

Answer (score 4):

I think its

> Thoughts

I convey the invisible,

I convey what can be felt,

> Thoughts are always invisible, we thoughts about what we felt.

But not seen,

Inside my heart,

> Thoughts can not seen

I am not as nice as I could seem to be

> Not all Thoughts seem to be nice always.

At the speed of a mere blink,

> Thoughts changes in every blink

I am very powerful

> Thoughts are powerful sometimes.

And can bring comfort,

> good thoughts bring comfort

Answer (score 2):

I convey the invisible,

> Words can convey the invisible

I convey what can be felt,

> Poetry etc. conveys feelings

But not seen,
Maybe just spoken?

Inside my heart,
I am not as nice as I could seem to be,

> Words can be malicious, have double meanings

That is because I deliver the invisible,
At the speed of a mere blink,

> Even just looking at text can allow you to sense the meaning.

I am very powerful,
And can bring comfort,

> Words can be a lot(just look at Hitler), but a mom, say comforts their children with words.

Across my horizons, I am free,

> People can say what ever they want

But still vulnerable to your opinion.

> Of course, people want you to approve of what they say

What am I?

> So I guess the spoken word?

---

Answer (score 1):

> Emoticons like frowny **:-(** & smiley **:-)** & frown-winky **;-(** & smile-winky **;-)** & etc.

Reference :

> Reference : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_emoticons

Reason :

> We use these to convey the invisible feelings, to bring comfortable feelings or bad feelings, though the reader might interpret these with own opinions

Comment: Very creative, but that's not the right answer.

Answer (score 1):

Could it be:

> A gaze?

I convey the invisible,
I convey what can be felt,

> A Gaze can transfer the feeling toward another person.

But not seen,
Inside my heart,

> You feel it when people gazing at you

I am not as nice as I could seem to be,

> A Gaze can be hostile

That is because I deliver the invisible,
At the speed of a mere blink,

> A Gaze takes merely a millisecond to transfer a message / feeling

I am very powerful,
And can bring comfort,

> A Gaze is powerful and can be a comfort from a lovely one

Across my horizons, I am free,
But still vulnerable to your opinion.

> You might think I am attracted to you / hostile if I gazed at you, it depends on your opinion.

What am I?

> a Gaze

Answer (score 1):

Could it be:

> The sun

I convey the invisible,

> The sun emits UV rays which we can't see

I convey what can be felt,

> You can feel the suns heat from earth

But not seen,

> We cant visibly UV light

Inside my heart,
I am not as nice as I could seem to be,

> The center of the sun is not a very nice place to be.

That is because I deliver the invisible,

> The sun also delivers gamma rays which is not nice to us.

At the speed of a mere blink,

> gamma rays and UV light travels very fast indeed.

I am very powerful,

> The sun is what powers the earth!

And can bring comfort,

> Some people enjoy the sunlight!

Across my horizons, I am free,

> Possible reference to a sunset or sunrise

But still vulnerable to your opinion.

> I guess some people might not like the sun.

What am I?

> The sun!

Answer (score 0):

On the lines of previous answers. 
I guess the answer could be

> (Facial) **Expressions**

I convey the invisible,

> We convey different emotions through our expressions

I convey what can be felt, But not seen,

> Emotions can only be felt.

Inside my heart, I am not as nice as I could seem to be,

> One might give a different expression than what is in one's heart.

That is because I deliver the invisible,

> Reference to emotions again

At the speed of a mere blink,

> Expressions are quick.

I am very powerful,

> Expressions are powerful

And can bring comfort,

> A good expression including a smile brings comfort.

Across my horizons, I am free,

> It's a free will.

But still vulnerable to your opinion.

> The other person can misjudge someone's expression.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is

> Body Language etiquette (good manners)

I convey the invisible,

> A persons real thoughts are invisible

I convey what can be felt,

> Always cannot hide behind the mask. (Refer LIE TO ME)

But not seen,

Inside my heart,

I am not as nice as I could seem to be,

That is because I deliver the invisible,

At the speed of a mere blink,

I am very powerful,

And can bring comfort,

Across my horizons, I am free,

But still vulnerable to your opinion.

What am I?